# twig: display variable only if it exists

Tags: twig, option-type

Is there a smart way to display/use a twig variable only if it exists?

Say, I've got a structure:

```
'opt1': {'visible': false, 'bundle': 'XxxBundle', 'name': 'label1'},
'opt2': {'visible': true, 'bundle': 'YyyBundle', 'name': 'label2', 'params': '/par1'},
```

and I use it in:

```
<a href="{{path(desc.bundle ~ '_' ~ action ~ desc.params)}}">
```

I would like twig to omit desc.params if it doesn't exist for distinct entry. Is there any smarter way than using `if` statement?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could just pass a default blank string to it.

```
<a href="{{path(desc.bundle ~ '_' ~ action ~ desc.params|default(''))}}">
```

This way if its not defined its just an empty string. You can read more about the default filter here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html

Comment: You can also just use `desc.params|default` (without the `('')`).

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to set `strict_variables` to false in you config.yml file:

```
twig:
    ...
    strict_variables: false
```

Comment: This will turn off the validation for all variables then and you may still need it in other place of your app. Just beware if you use this option.

Comment: I would beware again if once is not enough. Using `{{ val|default('') }}` is easy. I think we have enough late bugs with Javascript.